# Bash string with ".*" outputs multiple values when assigned to variable

Tags: bash

I have the following script

```
echo ".*/tools/.*"
var=$(echo ".*/tools/.*")
echo $var
```

The output of this is

```
.*/tools/.*
./tools/. ./tools/..
```

I would expect the output of this to be

```
.*/tools/.*
.*/tools/.*
```

Why is `var` being assigned multiple values? And how can I have it output the expected value?

`tools` is a folder in my current working directory, so I assume it has something to do with that.

GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Not when assigned, when echoed without enough quotes. The assignment is fine. The `echo` at the end is not.

Comment: Well, `var=$(echo ".*/tools/.*")` isn't _fine_, exactly -- it's incredibly inefficient (you're forking off a subprocess and capturing its output through a pipe just to achieve the effect of `var=".*/tools/.*"`)

Comment: The associated question answers mine. I could not for the life of me google the correct words to find it. Thanks for the insight.